# Self-containing trees

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose that $r^2-r-1=0$ and that $T$ is the tree with root $1$ such that the children of each node $x$ are $rx$ and $x+1$.  Remove all duplicates as they occur, and let $T(r)$ denote the remaining tree.  Does every complete subtree of $T(r)$ properly contain itself?  More generally, for what choices of $r$ does $T(r)$ properly contain itself?

Some background:

For $r^2-r-1=0$, the first 4 generations of $T(r)$ are $$(1), (r,2), (r+1,2r,3), (2r+1,r+2,2r+2,3r,4).$$

For every node $x$ of $T(r)$, let $T_x$ be the complete subtree with root $x$.  It appears that $T_2 = T_1$; i.e., the trees are identical (but with different labelings), so that $T_1$ properly contains itself.  The main question can be refined:  for each $x$, what is the least $y > x$ such that $T_x$ properly contains $T_y$ (assuming that there is such a $y$)?  Here, "least" refers to the order in which nodes appear in the construction of $T(r)$.

Comment: With duplicates removed, what does proper self-containment mean?  Are you looking instead for certain value-transforming endomorphisms of the tree?  Gerhard "Can Hardly Contain Myself Sometimes" Paseman, 2016.04.27.

Comment: I interpret it as the (infinite) being self-similar in some sense - every sub-tree contains a copy isomorphic to the original tree...

Comment: How do you remove duplicates? Or more precisely, if $rx = x'+1$, how do you decide whether to connect this node, which you want to make unique, to $x$ or to $x'$? Do you always make the same choice, or are you asking for any system of choices?

Comment: I suspect your tree is strongly related to the sort of things studied in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0798) (see esp. figure 5 on p. 9).

Comment: Gro-Tsen, duplicates are removed as they occur, where for given $x$, the child $rx$ occurs before $r+1$; e.g., the children of $r$ are $r^2$ and $r+1$, so that $r$ has only one child, $r+1$.

Comment: Shouldn't your $r^2+r+1=0$ be $r^2-r-1=0$?

Comment: Thanks, Gerry - I changed it.  (But the main question, not yet answered, extends to $r^2+r+1=0$, too.)

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, but it's too long for a comment.  Let me rewrite the rule for generating the tree in a more algorithmic fashion.  Instead of the element $a_0 + a_1 r$ (of the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[r]$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$), I'll just write $(a_0,a_1)$, where $a_0,a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The algorithm is then as follows:

- Start by creating the node $(1,0)$ as root, and add it to a queue.
- Repeatedly: remove the node $(a_0,a_1)$ from the start of the queue, create the node $(a_1,a_0+a_1)$ and then the node $(a_0+1,a_1)$, if they have not already been created, as its children, and add them to the queue (in that order, at the end).

We get something like this (writing `nx_y` for $(x,y)$, i.e., $x + ry$):

[image: seven first levels of tree]

If someone wishes to reproduce, the Perl code is as follows:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my @queue = ([1,0,0]);
my %hash;

print "digraph kimberling {\n";

while (1) {
    my $r = shift @queue;
    my $v0 = $r->[0];
    my $v1 = $r->[1];
    my $vg = $r->[2];  # Generation
    last if $vg > 5;
    my $vn = "${v0}_${v1}";
    $hash{$vn} = 1;
    my $l0 = $v1;
    my $l1 = $v0+$v1;
    my $lg = $vg+1;
    my $ln = "${l0}_${l1}";
    if ( ! $hash{$ln} ) {
        push @queue, [$l0,$l1,$lg];
        print "    n$vn -> n$ln;\n";
        $hash{$ln} = 1;
    }
    my $r0 = $v0+1;
    my $r1 = $v1;
    my $rg = $vg+1;
    my $rn = "${r0}_${r1}";
    if ( ! $hash{$rn} ) {
        push @queue, [$r0,$r1,$rg];
        print "    n$vn -> n$rn;\n";
        $hash{$rn} = 1;
    }
}

print "}\n";
```

(save the output to a `.dot` file and use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to produce the image).

This graph makes me unhappy for two reasons.  One is that there is a childless node ($(1,4)$).  The other is that the number of nodes in each level is *not*, as I had expected, given by the Fibonacci numbers.  But searching the first few terms in the OEIS, [I see that you got there first](https://oeis.org/A252864).  The sequence giving the number of children of each node in breadth order (2, 1,2, 2,1,2, 1,2,2,1,2, 1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2, 2,1,0,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2…) does not appear remarkable either.

Since the question is a form of "base $r$ representation" of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[r]$, I'll ask Jacques Sakarovitch what he thinks about it next time I see him.